# Calling java method from Oracle

Tags: java, oracle

I am using a method java in oracle DB, and writing the following code which is responsible of inserting the file name existing on the server and to which interface is related into the tables files_name.
This code is often used on several environments without any error.
But the problem exists only on a specific environment where the directory on the server is reading a non-existing file and in this way i am getting 2 records in the table files_name instead of 1 record.
In other words, I have only one file named BL_TR.csv, but when the java is called, it read BL_TR.csv and the old one.
I need to know how to get rid off this bug? and what is the cause of it?

```
create or replace procedure get_dir_list( p_directory in varchar2, intname in varchar2 )
as language java
name 'DirList.getList( java.lang.String, java.lang.String )';
/

create or replace and compile java source named dirlist as
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;

 public class DirList
 {
 public static void getList(String directory, String intname)
                throws SQLException
 {
 File path = new File( directory );
 String[] list = path.list();
 String element;

     for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
     {
         element = list[i];
         #sql { INSERT INTO SSDX_ENG.FILES_NAME (FILE_NAME, INTERFACE)
            VALUES (:element, :intname) };
     }
 }
 }
/
```

Any feedback is really appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: The answer is probably not in the code but in that specific environment. What's going on with that file?

Comment: @Rene, can the file be saved in the cache memory of the DB server?
From ftp i cannot see the file!!

Comment: ftp user and oracle user may have different privileges so they may not be looking at the same set of files. Ask an admin .

Comment: @Rene, thank you for your feedback. The problem was in the given access rights of the repository where the old file does not appear. After modification it appears normally so i could delete it.